In google sheets, how do I compare a cell to a range of regular expressions
I have a column that contains a number of different regular expressions, like this:



Regex Patterns




^abc


^def


^ghi


...


^xyz



I have another column with some strings:



Strings




abc123


def456



I want a third column that indicates the row number of the regex pattern that matches each string. So, for the example above, I want C1 to end up containing "1" (since "abc123" matches "^abc") and C2 to end up containing "2" (since "def456" matches "^def").
Example Result:



Regex Patterns
Strings
Matching Row




^abc
abc123
1


^def
def456
2



I tried using REGEXMATCH, but it seems to only look at a single regex cell, not a range. How can I achieve this in Google Sheets?

Okay, I solved this myself using scripts (though if anybody has an answer that doesn't involve custom scripts I'd love to hear it)
this is the script
function findMatchingRegexRow(queryArray, regexArray) {
var queryString=queryArray[0][0]

for (var i = 0; i < regexArray.length; i++) {
  var regex=regexArray[i][0]
  console.log("trying regex "+regex+" on "+queryString)
  if (new RegExp(regex).test(queryString)){
    console.log("matched on "+regex)
    return i+1
  }
}
} 

And then I reference it as you'd expect
=findMatchingRegexRow(B1, $A$1:$A$7)


Here's one approach you may test out:
=+tocol(map(A:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(regexmatch(B1,Σ),row(Σ),)))),1)


